# Elasticsearch - Composite aggregation max value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to get a max and min value of a date.

From the documentation I don't see a max option in composite:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_value_sources

I'd like something like this:

```
{
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{
      "intervals":{
         "composite":{
            "size":10000,
            "sources":[
               {
                  "id":{
                     "terms":{
                        "field":"id"
                     }
                  }
               },
               {
                 "minTime": {
                   "min": {
                     "script": "doc['createdAt'].value"
                   }
                 }
               },
               {
                 "maxTime": {
                   "max": {
                     "script": "doc['createdAt'].value"
                   }
                 }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Is it possible to add to this query or will I need a separate query for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `composite` aggregation allows you to paginate over buckets. `min` and `max` are metric aggregations that apply on each bucket (i.e. metric aggregations cannot be `sources` of composite aggregations) and must added as [sub-aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_sub_aggregations) to the composite aggregation, so what you need to do is the following instead:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "intervals": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 10000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "id"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "minTime": {
          "min": {
            "script": "doc['createdAt'].value"
          }
        },
        "maxTime": {
          "max": {
            "script": "doc['createdAt'].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```